# How to identify instance at which Webpage is refreshed in Wireshark

Tags: http, packet, wireshark

I am using Wireshark to monitor WebPage traffic. I would like to know the instance(Paket) at which the Webpage is refreshed. I could'nt find a concrete pattern when I look at the packets. Please let me know.

```
    eg:
    www.wireshark.com , www.wireshark.com 
    or
    www.wireshark.com , www.google.com ,www.wireshark.com
```

I can't depend on HostName,referer in Http Packet information as one Webpage might request multiple hosts to get images/adds etc

Answer (score 0):

i think you cant, because a refresh will act just like a simple request! there is nothing special with the refresh, it just sends a get request